# В массиве есть цифры,добавить рандомную цифру так чтобы не повторялись

Tags: javascript

Eсть массив, в котором число будут добавлен при каждом клике , теперь мне нужно добавить oдин случайное число, которого нет в этом массиве и числа не должны повторяться, это должен работать при каждом клике.

в результате этого кода бывает что повторяются.

```
let arr = [];
    function number(e) {
            let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
            arr.push(e);
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] == random) { random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9); i = 0 }
            }
            arr.push(random);
        }
```

Comment: Можно считать индекс массива случайным и неповторяющимся числом в этом случаи?

Comment: индекс по очереди добавления , а цифру случайно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял логику, то должно быть так:

```js
let arr = [];

function number() {
  if (arr.length < 9) {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
    while (arr.includes(random)) {
      random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
    }
    arr.push(random);
    console.log(arr);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="number()">+N</button>
```

Comment: возможно я неправильно сформулировал вопрос( на счет первого ответа),этот вариант решил проблему , спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```js
    function number() {
      let unique = new Set();
      while (unique.size < 9) {
        unique.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9))
      }
      return [...unique];
    }

console.log(number());
```

Вот без Set:

```js
    function number() {
      let uniqueArr = [];
      while (uniqueArr.length < 9) {
        let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        !uniqueArr.some(item => item === num) ? uniqueArr.push(num) : "";
      }
      return uniqueArr;
    }
console.log(number())
```

Добавление по одному элементу:

```js
let uniqueArr = [];
function number() {
  let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  while (uniqueArr.some(item => item === num)) {
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
  }
  uniqueArr.push(num);
}
number();
number();
number();
console.log(uniqueArr);
```

Comment: а без использование Set возможно?

Comment: Добавил без Set.

Comment: @Lukas: плюсанул только за краткость и скорость. Но, хорошо бы ещё, чтобы автор понятно написал, а Вы внимательно прочитали. Уникальное число добавляется, а массив увеличивается, при каждом вызове, а не формируется сразу.

Comment: @UModeL, спасибо. Действительно не досмотрел.

Answer (score 0):

поскольку речь у вас о цифрах, то можно взять известный массив, выкинуть оттуда все, что есть в исходном, и взять значение по произвольному индексу.

```js
function addRandom(arr){
   const digits = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
                    .filter(d => !arr.includes(d));
   const randIdx = Math.floor( Math.random()*digits.length);
   
   return arr.push(digits[randIdx]), arr ;
  
}

console.log(addRandom([1,2,3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function shuffle(arr) {
  let i = arr.length, ri;
  while (0 !== i) {
    ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    i--;
    [arr[i], arr[ri]] = [arr[ri], arr[i]];
  }

  return arr;
}

function generate(list) {
  const rlist = shuffle(list.slice());
  let i = 0;
  return () => (i < rlist.length) ? rlist[i++] : null;
}

const number = generate(Array(9).fill().map((_, i) => i + 1));
for (let i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
  console.log(number());
}
```